# wkhtmltopdf in docker-compose: No such file or directory: b'/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'

Tags: flask, docker-compose, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to install `wkhtmltopdf` in docker-compose. The package is installing correctly, but when I try to use it in flask app, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
server_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
server_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfkit/configuration.py", line 21, in __init__
server_1  |     with open(self.wkhtmltopdf) as f:
server_1  | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

Outside the docker-compose it works properly and this package path is `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`:

```
$ which wkhtmltopdf
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

**Server Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        libxrender1 \
        libjpeg62-turbo \
        fontconfig \
        libxtst6 \
        xfonts-75dpi \
        xfonts-base \
        xz-utils

RUN curl "https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb" -L -o "wkhtmltopdf.deb"
RUN dpkg -i wkhtmltopdf.deb

ENTRYPOINT ["wkhtmltopdf"]

FROM python:3.8.5
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "api.py"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
    server:
        build: ./api
        expose: 
            - 5000
    client:
        build: ./
        ports:
        - "7000:80"
```

Comment: did you find a solutions to this?

Comment: nope, but I may come back to this soon, I'll let you know if I figure out something

Comment: @linus I posted an answer, if you haven't figured out this yet, you can have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I came back to this issue after over a year and found the solution so thought I'd share, might be useful to someone.

This is the the `Dockerfile` of python service (flask to be precise) running with `wkhtmltopdf` installed inside of a container:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget fontconfig libfreetype6 libjpeg62-turbo libpng16-16 \
    libx11-6 libxcb1 libxext6 libxrender1 xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base libfontconfig1 \
    fontconfig-config libx11-data libxau6 libxdmcp6 xfonts-utils ucf fonts-dejavu-core \
    ttf-bitstream-vera fonts-liberation libbsd0 libfontenc1 libxfont2 \
    x11-common xfonts-encodings \
    && wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_arm64.deb \
    && dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_arm64.deb

RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", \
    "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", \
    "--workers", "8", \
    "--threads", "2", \
    "--access-logfile", "-", \
    "--log-file", "-", \
    "main:app"]
```

I install necessary dependencies and `wkhtmltopdf` from github releases. I use `arm64` build but if you need you can change architecture.

e.g. `amd64` arch: `https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_arm64.deb`

Then you can use it in the python service with a library like [pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/):

```py
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_string(pdf_content, 'output.pdf')
```

If the library will have difficulties with finding an executable installed in the container, here's a solution too:

```py
import subprocess
import pdfkit

executable = subprocess.run(['which', 'wkhtmltopdf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode().strip()
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=bytes(executable, 'utf-8'))
pdfkit.from_string(pdf_content, 'output.pdf', configuration=config)
```

Hope it helps!